# ASP.NET File Upload does not retain file on postback within update panel

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I have the following gridview which allows to upload a file in the footer section.

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="grdDocument_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="DocumentID" ShowFooter="true">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                    <RowStyle Width="10%" />
                    <FooterStyle Width="10%" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="lbInsert" runat="server" 
                                    CausesValidation="True" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DocumentID") %>' CommandName="Insert" ></asp:ImageButton>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers>
                                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lbInsert" />
                                    </Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# Eval("DocumentDescription") #%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" class="fileUpload" runat="server" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Somehow the FileUpload control does not retain uploaded file when it posts back. I tried adding PostbackTrigger for the link button but still no luck.

Code behind:

```
 private void grdDocument_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            var fileUpload = ((FileUpload)grdDocument.FooterRow.FindControl("fileUpload"));
            var document = new Document
            {
                Data = fileUpload.FileBytes,
                Description = fileUpload.FileName,
                Mime = fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType,
            };
       }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? let the user chose more than one file-upload and then upload all at once?

Comment: just one file upload. However, I want to integrate it inside the gridview control.  If I move fileupload and linkbutton outside gridview and add <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lbInsert" /> then it works.

Comment: can you provide some code behind? how are you retrieving the file in code?

Comment: That is how the FileUpload Control works. It does not keep the selectd file on PostBack.

Comment: Added code behind.

Comment: @VDWWD  - how do I fix it then?

Comment: You don't. A FileUpload needs a full PostBack. And the selected filename will still not be available after PostBack. If you want to have the FileUpload in the UpdatePanel you need to assign a Trigger: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074781/file-upload-control-inside-update-panel/50077018#50077018